# Heroku: Disable default behaviour of - Npm run start

Tags: node.js, heroku

Every time I deploy code to Heroku, it automatically looks to run the start script in package.json (NodeJS)

My app is set to run on a timer / scheduler and as such does not need to be run by Heroku when deployed.

How do I disable this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

you should create a [One-Off Dynos](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/one-off-dynos) whith a [Heroku Scheduler](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler) add-on.